# PySide2 を使い勉強をしようとしたところエラー発生

Tags: python, windows-8

Pythonの初学者です。PySide2を使ってみようとしたのですが、２以降のエラーが発生しました。VScodeを使い勉強してます。どなたかご教授頂けると幸いです。

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class DirMaker(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = DirMaker()
    win.show()

    result = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(result)
```

２．エラー内容

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.
```

Comment: この記事がそれらしい感じです。[qt.qpa plugin: could not find the qt platform plugin "windows" in "" \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56560515/9014308) `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH`という環境変数に対応するフォルダのパスを設定してみては？ 他に別の環境変数の記事もありますが。[Pythonで機械学習の勉強始めたら...](https://qiita.com/sukoppu1102/items/f5c00b520da0fa5d2ff3), [Error "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" while using matplotlib in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41994485/9014308) `QT_PLUGIN_PATH`, [qt python development - pyside2](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93085/qt-python-development-pyside2) `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS`

Comment: ありがとうございました。大変助かりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 後から見る人のためにも、どれが該当したのか、何か手順が必要なのか等を自己回答しておいてください。